# Using goto like function or method in OOP

Tags: php, oop

I have a class with many methods, and I would like to find ways to make the class jump from one method to another.

```
class foo{
  private $state = false; 
  function a(){
    if($this->state == false){
      //jumpt to method b
    }
    //other code 

  }   

 function b(){
   //
 }

function c(){

}

}
```

As you can see, I am trying to jump from `a()` to `b()` halting everything inside `a()` after that statement.

Comment: Why not using `$this->b();` instead of goto? Also, check this: http://xkcd.com/292/

Comment: GOTO is generally a highly discouraged pattern. Consider calling the method as briosheje suggests

Answer (score 2):

```
function a(){
if($this->state == false){
  $this->b();
  return;
  }

 //other code 

}
```

This will call `b()` and skip everything else in `a()` as you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

For a `gosub` type behavior where it will return back to `a()` and continue, then:

```
function a(){
    if($this->state == false){
      $this->b();
    }
    //other code 

  }
```

For a real `goto` type bahaviour to not return to `a()`:

```
function a(){
    if($this->state == false){
      return $this->b();
    }
    //other code 

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to put the rest of the code in an else:

```
class foo{
  private $state = false; 
  function a(){
    if($this->state == false){
      $this->b();
    }
    else {
      //other code 
    }

  }   

  function b(){
    //
  }

  function c(){

  }
}
```

Or you can return after you call b

```
if($this->state == false){
   $this->b();
   return;
}
```